# Different Manufactures related to Products/Categories

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, attribute-set

I have different manufactures for different products. The manufactures list can be very long if not filter by categories or products.

I am trying to know if there is a better way other than creating manufactures for each attribute set.

What is the best way to handle a lot of manufactures? How do people do when have very long manufactures list and different products?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any of the improved navigation extensions out there that allow for folded options or drop down menus.

Alternatively you can place products only in specific categories as you have mentioned.  The categories will show only the products in the particular category.

**Edit**: To address further detail given in comments.

Create individual attributes such as truck_manufacturers, tractor_manufacturers, etc.  List only the manufacturers you want in each of the attribute options.  For frontend you can still give them (the attributes) all frontend label of manufacturer if you wish.

Create also attribute sets in admin and add only the specific manufacturer attribute you want for said set.  Call attribute sets (tractors, trucks, etc). When creating new truck product, choose truck attribute set which has only truck_manufacturer attribute as a choice for manufacturer.

For frontend optionally use an extension that helps you display certain attributes in certain categories only.  But shouldn't be necessary if products are separated by category matching (tractors, trucks, etc).  Because category should only show attributes which have products that use them in that particular category.

Comment: searched about navigation layered extensions seems good for frontend, I found an useful extension thanks. For admin area, adding new product, I did not found any other solution.

Comment: How many manufacturers do you have.  I don't know how any solution could work for the backend since you need to see your choices.  Please accept my answer if it works for you.  Thank you.

Comment: I have some for different products. I want to show manufactures related to that category. I will give 24hs to choose an answer. If do not show a better solution I wil accept yours, thanks.

Comment: You will need to be more clear with examples of what you are trying to achieve in admin.

Comment: Example I have 200 manufactures for Trucks Parts and 200 manufactures for Tractors and 100 manufactures for Machines... When add a new product for Truck Parts I do not want to show the other manufactures (Tractors and Machines).

Comment: See my updated answer.